# Converting a series of events to durations

Tags: r

I'm not new to programming, but pretty new to R. I have a CSV with on and off events that looks like this:

```
           event_time      user_id    on
1 2016-01-29 05:23:32 Z388FPKNEAQF FALSE
2 2016-01-29 05:23:19 Z388FPKNEAQF  TRUE
3 2016-01-29 05:13:24 Z388FPKNEAQF FALSE
4 2016-01-29 05:13:09 Z388FPKNEAQF  TRUE
5 2016-01-29 05:13:07 Z388FPKNEAQF FALSE
6 2016-01-29 05:00:05 Z388FPKNEAQF  TRUE
```

To give you a sense of the data - row 1 and 2 represents a user turning on their screen at 05:23:19, and then turning it back off at 05:23:19. I would like to write some R to convert this into a frame where the rows from the source frame are collapsed into durations. I.e. row 1 and 2 would be collapsed into a single row that looks like this:

```
          event_start      user_id  duration
1 2016-01-29 05:23:19 Z388FPKNEAQF        12
```

I am struggling with how to do achieve with R. In a language like Python, it would be natural to do this with some form of loop, but in R it seems like it would be more idiomatic with a Reduce, perhaps? I am, however, not understanding at all how the syntax for this would look like and would appreciate some guidance to get me going.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="
event_time,user_id,on
1,2016-01-29 05:23:32,Z388FPKNEAQF,FALSE
2,2016-01-29 05:23:19,Z388FPKNEAQF,TRUE
3,2016-01-29 05:13:24,Z388FPKNEAQF,FALSE
4,2016-01-29 05:13:09,Z388FPKNEAQF,TRUE
5,2016-01-29 05:13:07,Z388FPKNEAQF,FALSE
6,2016-01-29 05:00:05,Z388FPKNEAQF,TRUE")
df$event_time <- as.POSIXct(df$event_time)
aggregate(
  event_time~., 
  data = transform(df, on=cumsum(!df$on)), 
  FUN = function(x) max(x)-min(x)
)
#        user_id id event_time
# 1 Z388FPKNEAQF  1  13.00000 
# 2 Z388FPKNEAQF  2  15.00000 
# 3 Z388FPKNEAQF  3  13.03333
```

?

Comment: This gives me the error :
Error in Summary.factor(c(6L, 5L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors